# Can't access font resource in Silverlight class library

Tags: xaml, silverlight-3.0, fonts, resources

I have a reasonably large Silveright 3.0 project on the go, and I'm having issues accessing a couple of custom font resources from within one of the assemblies.

I've got a working test solution where I have added a custom font as a resource, and can access it fine from XAML using:

```
<TextBlock Text="Test" FontFamily="FontName.ttf#Font Name" />
```

The test solution consists of the **TestProject.Application** and the **TestProject.Application.Web** projects, with all the fun and games obviously in the TestProject.Application project

However, when I try this in my main solution, the fonts refuse to show in the correct type face (instead showing in the default font). There's no difference in the way the font has been added to project between the test solution and the main solution, and the XAML is identical.

However, there is a solution layout difference. In the main solution, as well as having a **MainApp.Application** and **MainApp.Application.Web** project, I also have a **MainApp.Application.ViewModel** project and a **MainApp.Application.Views** project, and the problem piece of XAML is the in the MainApp.Application.Views project (not the .Application project like the test solution).

I've tried putting the font into either the .Application or .Application.Views project, tried changing the Build Action to Content, Embedded Resource etc, all to no avail.

So, is there an issue accessing font resources from a child assembly that I don't know about, or has anyone successfully done this?

My long term need will be to have the valid custom fonts being stored as resources in a separate .Application.FontLibrary assembly that will be on-demand downloaded and cached, and the XAML controls in the .Application.Views project will need to reference this FontLibrary assembly to get the valid fonts. I've also tried xcreating this separate font library assembly, and I can't seem to get the fonts from the second assembly.

As some additional information, I've also tried the following font referencing approaches:

```
<TextBlock Text="Test" FontFamily="/FontName.ttf#Font Name" />
<TextBlock Text="Test" FontFamily="pack:application,,,/FontName.ttf#Font Name" />
<TextBlock Text="Test" FontFamily="pack:application,,,/MainApp.Application.Views;/FontName.ttf#Font Name" />
<TextBlock Text="Test" FontFamily="pack:application,,,/MainApp.Application.Views;component/FontName.ttf#Font Name" />
```

And a few similar variants with different assembly references/sub directories/random semi colons.

And so far nothing works... anyone struck this (and preferably solved it)?

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me:

```
... FontFamily="/(DLL);Component/(DIR-optional)/(Font_file)#(Font_name)"/> ...
```